# How do I debug multiprocess application with Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb, fork

I'm trying to debug my application written in C with Eclipse. There are two fork() calls there so I need to debug 3 processes simultaniously. I checked "Automatically debug forked processes" in the project debug configuration window and tried to debug, but Eclipse doesn't allow me to switch between debugging contexts of different processes. The breakpoints I have installed for child processes don't hit. I also tried debug with "Non-stop mode", but it fails with segmentation fault just after start. What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You don't debug with Eclipse. You debug with `gdb` (which you might start in Eclipse). So read the [documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html)

Comment: @Basile, sure. The reason I ask this question here is exectly because gdb docs did not clarify anything.